# StanfordCoreNLP NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Map;


import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;


public class Stanforder {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = "";
        File myFile =  new File("C:\\master\\stanford\\txt\\43711.txt");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    //sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                text = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(text);
        // read some text in the text variable
         // Add your text here!

        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);

        // these are all the sentences in this document
        // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

        for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
          // traversing the words in the current sentence
          // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
          for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            // this is the text of the token
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
            // this is the POS tag of the token
            String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
            // this is the NER label of the token
            String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
          }

          // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
          Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

          // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
          SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the example form Stanford's site and I was trying to read the contents from a file and I am getting the below Exception at the line where the StanfordCoreNLP (props) constructor is called:

Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Generics.newHashMap()Ljava/util/Map;    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.(AnnotatorPool.java:27)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.getDefaultAnnotatorPool(StanfordCoreNLP.java:303)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:256)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
>     at Stanforder.main(Stanforder.java:35)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This means that you have an inconsistent set of compiled classes. Down there, there is a call to a method of some class, but the method doesn't exist any more. Normally, the compiler would check that, but if you replace the correct class with one that doesn't have that method, you'll get this `NoSuchMethodError`.

Answer (score 4):

Refer the 9th question in

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#nosuchmethoderror

It says,

> "It is because you also have old versions of one or more Stanford NLP
>   tools on your classpath"

and also have a look on,

https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-November/004357.html

which says,

> Clearly there is some jar file incompatibility.  Do you have any older
>   versions of our tools in your classpath?